# How to find the maximum number of edges that exactly contain x vertices in a k-uniform hypergraph？

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs, hypergraphs

Help me please. I really need some articles about this problem. Or are there any other extremal k-uniform hypergraph about this problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry，but I exactly need some answers with specific constraints. Because it is a NP hard problem in general.